# PDF Editor control for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf

I'm looking for a PDF editor control for a WPF application.

The control should: 1) have eraser feature, 2) allow user to clear margins (say of an inch or user-specified amount), 3) allow removing/re-ordering pages. I'm happy to buy this, but haven't found any workable solutions yet.

Any ideas? Do I need to roll my own?

If I do need to roll my own, I can get to creating an ImageSource from each page of the PDF via Ghostscript.net. Any suggestions for an image editor control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete solution is a cocktail of 3 different libraries:

- [Ghostscript .Net](https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/) for initial rasterization of PDFs
- [Image processor](http://imageprocessor.org/) for performing edits to the images
- My own UI using WPF Canvases